error message after tryign to install a python package
I've already downloaded get-pip.py twice now, and whenever i type pip --version in the terminal (i use visual studio code btw) it always prints out "Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"c:\python39\python.exe"  "C:\Python39\Scripts\pip.exe" --version': The system cannot find the file specified."
I've been struggling because I can't find answers anywhere and it won't let me download any python packages at all. I've already tried downloading the latest version of python and adding it to PATH as well

Are you sure that the Python installation path and the Scripts folder are in your system's PATH environment variable?
If you not sure, u should go to System Properties -> Advanced -> Environment Variables and look for Path system variables section.
Make sure you have path like this
C:\Python39
C:\Python39\Scripts\

yes, ive checked and they are the top two in the PATH

so, u may solve this problem with that link
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cxSwtZLiZPM
if u get another error, send it again
